# Is there any way to make Windows 8 blue screen intentionally?

Tags: windows-8, bsod

There used to be a debug option involving a registry hack on older versions of Windows that let me blue screen a system on purpose. I'd like to see if my usual blue screen diagnosis tools work on Windows 8, so would there be a way to convince windows to BSOD on purpose in a controllable way?

Comment: [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Force-a-Blue-Screen-in-Windows) does not work any more?

Comment: You might want to try posting that as an answer in case it works. It seems the most predictable option I have not tried it yet. Currently backing up my system to take the chance on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Easy way to do this on older versions is set out [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Force-a-Blue-Screen-in-Windows).

Basically,

*For PS/2 Keyboards:*

- Open **`Regedit`**
- Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\i8042prt\Parameters`
- **Add a new DWORD (32-bit) Registry value** here with name = `CrashOnCtrlScroll` and value = `1`
- Now you close regedit and restart PC
- Finally hold down <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> and press <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> **twice** to trigger the BSOD.

*For USB Keyboards:*

- Open **`Regedit`**
- Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\kbdhid\Parameters`
- **Add a new DWORD (32-bit) Registry value** here with name = `CrashOnCtrlScroll` and value = `1`
- Now you close regedit and restart PC
- Finally hold down <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> and press <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> **twice** to trigger the BSOD.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method that works on Windows Vista and might work on 8 (not verified on 7 or 8):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ACPI]
"Start"=dword:00000004
```

Save it as a `.reg` file and run it. Your computer will blue screen on reboot. Return to last good configuration or change the value back to 0 to fix it.

[Source](http://www.petri.co.il/forums/showthread.php?t=20936)

Installing incompatible drivers can work as well.
Try to install out-dated video-drivers.

Comment: Overclocking and changing frequency/voltages for RAM (!!!) could cause hardware damage. And both of those and outdated video drivers may cause instability, but it's not really predictable ('crash on demand'), more 'crash at some random time from right now to never'...

Comment: Yes, this can be dangerous, I didn't say it is safe.
That's why you should be quite familiar with what you are doing.
The guy, can actually take faulty memory DIMM and perform test. 
Of course, the safest way is to download already available dumps from Internet and simply import to his tool.
Besides, there are chances that old tricks won't cause BSODs on new OS.
I simply provided a couple of alternatives.

Comment: I'm just leaving a note that this *is* dangerous. Not everyone here is experienced with computers, so it's better to be explicit about dangerous actions than just leave out assurances of safety...

Comment: Agree that this is worth mentioning.
For OP the safest way would be to download dumps from internet.

Comment: I agree with these comments and do not recommend this. You could be left with a system that doesn't boot at all!

Answer (score 0):

Copied (in part) from That Brazilian Guy's [answer here](https://superuser.com/a/699312/10165), with permission

The [command line interface](https://diskcryptor.net/wiki/Console) for the [DiskCryptor](https://diskcryptor.net) Open source partition encryption software includes a `-bsod` parameter, the wiki says it will

> Erase all keys in memory **and generate BSOD**