# How to protect (prank from) an unlocked computer

Tags: windows-7, windows, security

I've set myself up as a target at work by being big on security and "encouraging" my co-workers to lock their computers.

I've done the usual stuff, changing mouse cursor to loading indicator, their chrome icon locks their computer, screensaver BSOD etc. But now they are collectively waiting for me to leave my computer (or phone) unlocked to get me back.

I'd love to be able to leave it unlocked once or twice and prank them anyway. Or know I'd be ok if I forgot to lock it.

What are some ways I could do this? Batch files, system settings, applications? I'm a software developer so pranks that require a small application to be written would be no problem.

I have windows 7 as do most of my coworkers. Also if there's a better site for this than I can relocate but I saw the question about messing with someone's computer getting good responses.

How can I prank the pranksters, or at the very least protect my computer if I leave it unlocked?

Comment: Related: [How to mess up a PC running Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/275894/194694), [Convincingly “breaking” a system for a non technical user](http://superuser.com/q/699278/194694)

Comment: Good link, but only one of those answers really applies. Though I'll definitely be taking that one and trying it! Thanks!

Comment: [On resume, display logon screen](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/15322-screen-saver-password-protection-enable-disable.html) | [Bluetooth Auto Lock Gadget](http://mgrowan.wordpress.com/2008/11/22/bluetooth-auto-lock-gadget-released/)

Comment: Magnetic cuff-link so it auto locks when you pull your left hand away from your keyboard.